# Why can this Kotlin Object Inherit from itself?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

I am trying to interface with TeamCity using Kotlin.

When you convert a project to Kotlin (from .xml) you will have a file called Project.kt which is where you can set all your configurations.

With no editing mine looks like this:

```
object Project : Project(/* Some Function Literal with Receiver */)
```

This looks like circular inheritance? There are imports that I am omitting, but surely that wouldn't make that big of a difference? Could the name be interpreted in different ways depending on where it appears in the file?

My mind is interpreting the object signature like this:

- **object** = Object declaration for singleton.
- **Project** (first occurrence) = Name of object.
- **:** = Inheritance marker.
- **Project** (second occurrence) = Base class to inherit from.
- **()** = Constructor call to the base class.

Is this circular inheritance or have I missed something big about Kotlin? I have looked [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) and [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) and can't seem to find my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming qualified classes `other.Project` and `my.Project`, you'd have two different classes defined with the same name, in different packages.

Since `my.Project` is defined as a Singleton, you cannot extend from it and the actual base class is `other.Project`. *Kotlin* is clever enough to differentiate. If you would try to do the same with a class declaration, you'd get a circular inheritance.

You could even try to force extending from the Singleton explicitly, but then you'll have the error *Cannot inherit from a Singleton*. So basically this only works well if you imported the right classes.

Comment: That's a rather clever compiler!